# How to remove link to profile under title, when rendering a profile as block in the module Profile2

Tags: 7, blocks, views

I'm rendering a user customer profile in a form using the code:

```
$profile = profile2_load_by_user($account, 'customer');
$form['customer_profile'] = array(
    '#type' => 'item',
    '#markup' => render($profile->view('block')),
);
```

which works rather well, except that the title (in H2 tags) is rendered as a link back to the profile.

I want to get rid of that link, but as there seems to be no obvious property, to specify if you do or do not want a backlink. Not in the `$build` array parameter of [hook_entity_view_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_entity_view_alter/7), nor in the `$elements` parameter for a ['#pre_render' callback](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_render/7). In a '#post_render' callback, it's too late because the link is already inserted into html.

So, how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link is part of template file `profile2.tpl.php` defined as `$title` and it appear for non page display modes as described by the template code.

```
<?php if (!$page): ?>
<h2<?php print $title_attributes; ?>>
    <a href="<?php print $url; ?>"><?php print $title; ?></a>
</h2>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The short possible solution can be to unset `title` variable implementing `hook_preprocess_profile2`. But to remove whole markup you will have to overwrite theme registry implementing `hook_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry)` to replace template against `profile2`.

```
$theme_registry['profile2'] = array(
  'render element' => 'elements',
  'template' => 'profile2_custom',
  'path' => path_to_theme(),
);
```

Comment: Thanks, even though your post contains some errors (for example: hook_preprocess_profile2.tpl.php is never included, but hook_preprocess_entity.tpl.php is), you provided more than enough clues to figure something out.

Comment: What I ended up doing was making a copy of profile2.tpl.php as profile2--customer--block.tpl.php, and remove the link from there.

Comment: hook_preprocess_profile2() is suggested in profile2.api.php (part of profile2 module). See the definition of hook_profile2_view_alter(). I think you was expecting hook_preprocess_profile2.tpl.php as a template file. In-fact 'profile2' entry in theme registry expects a template profile2.tpl.php in module's directory. On the other hand the hook_preprocess_profile2 is invoked just before to render this template to manipulate variables in the scope of that template. :)

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to get a more detailed explanation of your solution to this problem? I am having this exact problem. I would comment but I can not.